# What entropy sources are available on heroku?

Tags: heroku, cryptography, entropy

I would like to deploy an application to heroku which needs to be able to generate cryptographically secure random numbers. What entropy sources can I use?

Comment: Related question: when heroku boots up a new machine (presumably with some image) does its entropy pool get seeded with the same data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Heroku dyno is basically an Ubuntu Server VM, so you should have access to `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` like you would on any other Linux-based OS.

If you're using Ruby/Rails, you should probably be using `SecureRandom` (or `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` for older versions of Ruby and Rails) for this.